# Modifying a document's ContentType with Sharepoint 2010 web services

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

it seems like the Sharepoint List Service's [UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx) is the right function to use, but what is the right xml to use to actually update a specific document's content type?  So, if I had this to start:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement updates = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
updates.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
updates.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "0");
updates.SetAttribute("ViewName", "");
updates.InnerXml = "<Method ID="1" Cmd="Update"><what should go here?/></Method";

ListService.UpdateListItems(repositoryId, updates);
```

What should the Inner xml look like to update the list item's contenttype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me, maybe would help:

```
<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field><Field Name='ContentType'>SubFolder</Field><Field Name='BaseName'>MyFolder</Field> <Field Name='ID'>New</Field></Method>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is accepted as valid, and changed the ContentType of a list item:

```
updates.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID'>" + listItemId + 
"</Field><Field Name=\"Title\">ModifiedFile</Field>"+
"<Field Name='FSObjType'>0</Field><Field Name='ContentType'>" + contentTypeName + 
"</Field></Method>";
```